# Java Abstract Class And Generics

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract-class

I'm trying to modify a class `AuthenticatedUser` to store a list of `AdminRole`'s.  `AuthenticatedUser` is a class used by all my applications; it gets put into a session when the user logs in successfully. Now I want to add a list of authorization roles to the user session. However each application defines the an `AdminRole` class a little differently. For example, my DataCenter application stores in the database:

```
  employee_id
  role_name
  site_name
  receive_email
```

Not all of my applications will need the receive_email field or may want to extend their own methods.  I figured this called for an abstract class.  But Eclipse is complaining about the wrong Type on the Authorized_role_list setter here in this snippet.

```
  DataCenterAdminRoleDAO dcAdminDao = new DataCenterAdminRoleDAO();
  try {
      List<DataCenterAdminRole> authorized_roles = dcAdminDao.getAuthorizedRoleListByBadge(authenticatedUser.getBadge());
      authenticatedUser.setAuthorized_role_list(authorized_roles);

=== Classes

public class AuthenticatedUser extends Employee implements Serializable {   
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  private List<AdminRole> authorized_role_list;
  ...
}

public abstract class AdminRole implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  private String role_name; //regular, admin, editor, etc..
  private String site_id;  //company branches
  ...
}

public class DataCenterAdminRole extends AdminRole implements Serializable {
```

Obviously a fix is to return a list of `AdminRole` in my Datacenter implemetation but I thought by extending the abstract class I could pass the subclass. What am I missing?

Comment: Please try to create a [sscce](Short, Self Contained, Correct Example). I realize you have compilation error but you can leave that line commented. Also paste the actual error reported by Eclipse without rephrasing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's the setter that is giving you trouble you can use a lower bound with a wildcard on the `authorized_roles_list`

```
private List<? extends AdminRole> authorized_role_list;
....
public setAuthorized_role_list(List<? extends AdminRole> authorized_roles) {
...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Generics do not behave like the rest of Java. Auto casting up does not occur, so if a method calls for `List<List>`, you can't hand it a `List<ArrayList>`. Similarly here, if your setter called for List, you cannot hand it a `List<? extends AdminRole>`, unless you define it as `List<? extends AdminRole>`. You can, however, override the setter method to take a `List<DataCenterAdminRole>` if you want, or convert your `List<DataCenterAdminRole>` to a `List<AdminRole>`, or just change your setter / the field to be a capture type `<? extends AdminRole>`

Answer (score 1):

A `List<Orange>` is not a `List<Fruit>`, even if Orange is a Fruit. If it was a `List<Fruit>`, you could do the following:

```
List<Orange> orangeList = new ArrayList<Orange>();
List<Fruit> fruitList = orangeList;
fruitList.add(new Apple());
```

And it would thus completely break the type-safety of generic collections, since a list of oranges would contain an apple. The AuthenticatedUser should contain a `List<? extends AdminRole>` to be able to do what you're doing.

Comment: To better understand your analogy, I coded this in Eclipse.  I get an error on line #2. Eclipse suggest changing type of fruitList to List<Orange>.  I guess this is what you are pointing out, that Eclipse is preventing me from breaking type safety.